# How to convert string to uint8[] in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, string

Now I use the follow code to init `buf[]`, but I wanna pass a string to `buf[]`, then how can I convert string to `buf[]`? Thanks!

```
UInt8 buf[] = "hello world";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that, by "string", you meant an `NSString *`.

The length of a string is unknown at compile-time, so you can't define a `UInt8 buf[]` to contain the value. You have to either pre-specify the length (e.g., `UInt8 buf[100]`), or copy the string into heap memory and refer to it with a `UInt8 *buf`.

For the first approach:

```
UInt8 buf[100];
strncpy(buf, str.UTF8String, sizeof(buf));
```

For the second, this is one way to do it:

```
UInt8 *buf = strdup(str.UTF8String);
// Don't forget to call free(buf) later.
```